# mfc dialog base application, create dynamic number of items (drop down list)

Tags: mfc, dialog

[image]

Situation:
I am trying to create an dialog base application using mfc that first scan ip from range 192.168.0.x to 192.168.0.y (variable). Every ip responsed will be recorded and display on my dialog application and then they will be grouped by user. User will be using a list of combobox to group them.

Problem:
However, due to the number of response is a variable, I should create a list of variable number of combobox list and I don't know how to do it.
Any help is very appreciate.

Comment: Would a CListCtrl be a better choice to show your data?

Comment: @rrirower do u have any reference about that ? thx ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be to use a differtent kind of UI. Either a List control or a Grid control.

In the Grid control you can use a combo box.
[Here a sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/500/Using-comboboxes-in-the-MFC-Grid-Control) for this.

Or use a list control with a Combo Box. [Here a sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5709/Customized-Report-List-Control-With-In-Place-Combo) for this.

You can also just enlarge your Dialog and just create CComboBox items per new and Create. In the Create code you can use different IDs for the command handling. With On_COMMAND_RANGE you can create a central handler.

Answer (score 1):

Just empty your combo when you start scanning and perform a [CComboBox::AddString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9y44b47.aspx) for each ip-address that you discover

Comment: but i have to create variable number of combobox... the number of combobox is different from how much ip replied... if i create empty combobox first i still only can create constant number of combobox right ?

Comment: This comment is after the question has been edited: you could also create just two combo boxes, one containing the groups; once a group has been selected, the second combo could be filled with the ip-addresses of that group